# Running a Docker image on Windows 10 using a Makefile

Tags: windows, docker, makefile

I apologize if this a silly question but when I type inside PowerShell of Window 10:

```
docker run -it -v C:\Users\Bob\Documents\test:/usr/python -w /usr/python 
bob/python
```

It works just fine and I receive the following prompt:

```
root@63eef6ac2b96:/usr/python#
```

To avoid repeating the command over and over, I build a makefile that has the following command

```
docker:
    docker run -it -v C:\Users\Bob\Documents\test:/usr/python -w /usr/python bob/python
```

when I try to execute

```
make docker
```

I receive the following error

```
PS C:\Users\Bob\documents\test> make docker
docker run -it -v C:\Users\Bob\Documents\test:/usr/python -w /usr/python 
bob/python
c:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from 
daemon: the working directory 'C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/python' i
s invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.
See 'c:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
make.exe": *** [docker] Error 125
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use a `Makefile`. Docker compose is what you are looking for.

In brief, you need to create a `docker-compose.yml` file and inside it describe all the desired steps. I am not aware of your full setup but I will try to provide a skeleton for your `docker-compose` file.

```
version: '3.7'(depends on your docker engine version)
services:  
  python_service(add a name of your choice):
    build: build/ (The path of image's Dockerfile)
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\Bob\Documents\test:/usr/python
    working_dir: /usr/python
```

In the snippet above:

- `-v` flag replaced with `volumes` section
- `-w` flag replced with `working_dir` section

**How to use**:

Now that your `docker-compose` file is ready, you need to use it. So you do not need to remember/repeat the `docker run` command, you will simple execute `docker-compose up` in the directory where your compose file is located and you will have your container up and running.

Note that this is a simple example on how to use `docker-compose`. It is a powerful feature allowing to start containers from multiple images, creating networks and much more. I would recommend you to read the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) for additional information.